# Cómo obtener la información de un div y mostrarlo en otro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un div que contiene la cantidad de visitas de una página en la misma web, quiero saber cómo puedo mostrar esa cantidad en un div que se encuentra en la página principal, cómo puedo llamar esa información?

```
<!-- DIV DE LA PÁGINA -->
<div id="views">145,125</div>

<!-- DIV QUE SE ENCUENTRA EN LA PÁGINA PRINCIPAL -->
<div id="quanty-view"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución rápida y pensando en que los navegadores de los usuarios soporten `localStorage` de `HTML5` sería:

Primero obtenemos la información a guardar

HTML:

```
<div id="views">145,125</div>
```

javascript:

```
var informacion = document.getElementById('views');

//Guardar la información que quieras mostrar
if(window.localStorage){
    window.localStorage.setItem('vistas', informacion.textContent);
}
```

Y en la página principal la puedes mostrar en tu `div`

HTML:

```
<div id="quanty-view"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var vistas = document.getElementById('quanty-view');
vistas.textContent = window.localStorage.getItem('vistas');
```

El método `setItem` de `localStorage` te permite guardar de manera local (en el navegador del usuario) algo de información mediante una `clave` que no es más que un `string` que sirve como identificador, en este caso las vistas.
El método `getItem` también de `localStorage` permite obtener o recuperar valores que han sido guardados anteriormente.

Sin embargo yo recomendaría que usarás un método más `confiable` cómo guardar la información que quieras mostrar en una base de datos en el servidor y después mostrarla con algún lenguaje de programación que pueda ejecutarse también en el servidor, como `php` que es el más usado.